# python: create dictionary equivalent of xml with attribute and value

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, attributes

I need to create an XML of below format:

```
<parent name="abc">123</parent>
```

The python code (3.x) is:

```
my_dict = {} #ln1
my_dict["parent"] = {} #ln2
my_dict["parent"]["_name"] = "abc" #ln3
my_dict["parent"] = 123 #ln4
```

This just creates

```
<parent>123</parent>
```

If I comment ln4, it creates

```
<parent name="abc" />
```

I am just not able to create an attribute and set the value of element. Any help? Any packages that could help?

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
my_dict = {} #ln1
my_dict["parent"] = {} #ln2
my_dict["parent"]["_name"] = "abc" #ln3
my_dict["parent"] = 123 #ln4
```

This will:

1. Create and empty dictionary and assign it to the variable my_dict.

You now have `my_dict = {}`.

2. Create the key "parent" in the dictionary my_dict and set its value to an empty dictionary.

You now have `my_dict = {"parent": {}}`.

3. Create the key "_name" in the dictionary my_dict["parent"] and set its value to "abc".

You now have `my_dict = {"parent: {"_name": "abc"}}`

4. Overwrite the value of the key "parent" in the dictionary my_dict to 123.

You now have `my_dict = {"parent: 123}`

Since you haven't supplied the code that "just creates" the xml code, I cannot show you how to correct your example. If you provide it I'll update my answer.